# Adding rules in Angular fails

Tags: html, angular

I have a problem with adding simple rule to angular. I'm following guide (https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/route-configuration/), and my code looks like following:

app.module.ts

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from "@angular/router";


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    ContentComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    CuriositiesComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true}),
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SwiperModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Unfortunatelly, during compilation there is some error, and I have no idea where is the problem:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(20,11): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ declarations: (ModuleWithProviders | typeof HomeComponent | typeof AppComponent)[]; imports: (t...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'.
  Types of property 'declarations' are incompatible.
    Type '(ModuleWithProviders | typeof HomeComponent | typeof AppComponent)[]' is not assignable to type '(any[] | Type<any>)[]'.
      Type 'ModuleWithProviders | typeof HomeComponent | typeof AppComponent' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'.
        Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'.
          Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'.
            Property 'apply' is missing in type 'ModuleWithProviders'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`declarations` metadata option of `NgModule` decorator only holds `Component`, `Pipe` & `Directive`. You can not put `RouterModule` inside `declarations` option. You should put inside `imports` option

```
imports: [
   //Removed RouterModule from declarations and shifted inside import. 
   RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true}),
   BrowserModule,
   SwiperModule
],
```